# Mostrar imagen escalada con OpenCV imshow()

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn

Tengo una imagen de 3000x4000 y estoy usando el siguiente código:

```
import cv2 as cv
im = cv.imread('we.jpg', cv.IMREAD_IGNORE_ORIENTATION) # Para que la imagen salga horizontal
cv.imshow("", im)
```

Y la imagen se me abre a escala real, lo que me impide visualizarla en su totalidad (sólo se ve un trozo de la imagen).

¿Hay alguna forma de que se vea la imagen escalada de tal manera que pueda operar con sus dimensiones pero a la hora de visualizarla se vea entera?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se puede y deberías hacer es ajustar el tamaño de la imagen a uno que sea consistente para ser visualizado en tu pantalla. El ajuste lo haces con `resize()` pero lo ideal, entiendo, es mantener la proporción de la imagen, para esto puedes usar el copio el código de esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58126805/6836377)

```
def ResizeWithAspectRatio(image, width=None, height=None, inter=cv2.INTER_AREA):
    dim = None
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    if width is None and height is None:
        return image
    if width is None:
        r = height / float(h)
        dim = (int(w * r), height)
    else:
        r = width / float(w)
        dim = (width, int(h * r))

    return cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=inter)
```

A la hora de mostrar tu imagen:

```
import cv2 as cv
im = cv.imread('we.jpg', cv.IMREAD_IGNORE_ORIENTATION) # Para que la imagen salga horizontal

resized = ResizeWithAspectRatio(im, width=1024) # Ajustamos manteniendo un ancho de 1024
cv2.imshow('resize', resized)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: lo que he hecho al final ha sido abrir la imagen con matplotlib, que me la abre y me la muestra con las dimensiones pero de tal manera que puedo ver la imagen completa sin estar enormemente agrandada. Igualmente muchas gracias por la respuesta!